# How to combine some journal papers latex files and make a single file which includes all with their own format?

Tags: latex

I am writing my PhD thesis as a combination of my papers. First I wrote an "introduction" chapter, then chapter 2, 3 and 4 are my papers and the chapter 5 is "conclusion". All of these 5 chapters have been written in separate latex files. Now, I was wondering how can I put all of them in a single file so that I can produce outlines of materials and figures?

I know how to combine simple files, but in this case, 3 of them are journal papers with different formatting (e.g. one of them is 1 column and the other is two columns). According to my university rules I should add the journal paper chapters in their own format (the format which they were published) and not a unify format similar to the others.
Now, I was wondering how can I do this?
I got errors when I compiled which says the formatting is defined in the main latex file which has link to the others and you can not define separate documents, or I have used "\maketitle" for writing the title of each paper but I got error that this instruction is only for the main file and so on...

how can I manage this? thanks

Comment: You could include the separately compiled articles via the `pdfpages` package. It has also options like `addtotoc` and `addtolist` where you can add the things from the article to your toc, list of figures etc.